# FullCalendar header title not showing

Tags: javascript, html, css, fullcalendar

When I first implemented FullCalendar on this project it was working perfecty, but now the header title is gone.

When I inspect may page I can see that the title is getting displayed in the center of the calendar. But, somehow it is not showing.

Here is my javascript code:

```
 $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
      header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,listWeek,'
      },
      height: "auto",
      editable: true,
      navLinks: true,
      eventLimit: true,
      events: {
        url: 'http://localhost:8000/calendar/calendar-php/get-events.php',
        error: function() {
          $('#script-warning').show();
        }
      },
      loading: function(bool) {
        $('#loading').toggle(bool);
      },
    });
```

[image: This is how my calendar looks like]

The html generated code is something like this:

```
<div class="fc-center">
<h2>Agosto 2017</h2>
</div>
```

I even tried setting css styles to make it visible, but it didn't work.

Comment: have you check if add some css aditionals may overwrite clases?

Comment: ... or try to find the div on the inspector and check if it's hidden because it's container is `overflowing`... add `overflow:visible` to its parent just to check that it's not hidden somewhere.

Comment: Just solved it, guys! Thanks!

I don't know why, but it was an animated modal I put to edit the calendar data. It was before the calendar render in the code, I just removed it and put in the end of the page and the header came back!